# How to show exact decimals in horizontal stacked bar chart

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have found a code for creating stacked bar charts on https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/horizontal_barchart_distribution.html.

Problem is that decimal places are not shown in the graph. In the code i've found there are no decimals in the list, but if you change them to decimals there are not shown (see code below). 
If tried to change str to float in ax.text(x, y, str(int(c)) line. That actually shows decimals, but all of them are 0.
many thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


category_names = ['Strongly disagree', 'Disagree','Neither agree nor   
agree', 'agree', 'Strongly agree']

results = {
    'Question 1': [(10), (14.99), (17.01), (32), (26)]
}


def survey(results, category_names):
    labels = list(results.keys())
    data = np.array(list(results.values()))
    data_cum = data.cumsum(axis=1)
    category_colors = plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn')(
        np.linspace(0.15, 0.85, data.shape[1]))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9.2, 5))
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    ax.set_xlim(0, np.sum(data, axis=1).max())

    for i, (colname, color) in enumerate(zip(category_names, category_colors)):
        widths = data[:, i]
        starts = data_cum[:, i] - widths
        ax.barh(labels, widths, left=starts, height=0.5,
                label=colname, color=color)
        xcenters = starts + widths / 2

        r, g, b, _ = color
        text_color = 'white' if r * g * b < 0.5 else 'darkgrey'

        for y, (x, c) in enumerate(zip(xcenters, widths)):
            ax.text(x, y, str(int(c)), ha='center', va='center',
                color=text_color)
    ax.legend(ncol=len(category_names), bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1),
              loc='lower left', fontsize='small')

    return fig, ax


survey(results, category_names)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `str(int(c))`, you first convert the number to integer, thereby dropping the decimals, and then convert that into a string. To get the desired output, either use `str(c)`, or if you want to be able to control the format of the number better (such as choosing the number of digits after the decimal point) replace `str(int(c))` by `'{:.2f}'.format(c)`

```
category_names = ['Strongly disagree', 'Disagree','Neither agree nor agree', 'agree', 'Strongly agree']

results = {
    'Question 1': [(10), (14.99), (17.01), (32), (26)]
}


def survey(results, category_names):
    labels = list(results.keys())
    data = np.array(list(results.values()))
    data_cum = data.cumsum(axis=1)
    category_colors = plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn')(
        np.linspace(0.15, 0.85, data.shape[1]))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9.2, 5))
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    ax.set_xlim(0, np.sum(data, axis=1).max())

    for i, (colname, color) in enumerate(zip(category_names, category_colors)):
        widths = data[:, i]
        starts = data_cum[:, i] - widths
        ax.barh(labels, widths, left=starts, height=0.5,
                label=colname, color=color)
        xcenters = starts + widths / 2

        r, g, b, _ = color
        text_color = 'white' if r * g * b < 0.5 else 'darkgrey'

        for y, (x, c) in enumerate(zip(xcenters, widths)):
            ax.text(x, y, '{:.2f}'.format(c), ha='center', va='center',
                color=text_color)
    ax.legend(ncol=len(category_names), bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1),
              loc='lower left', fontsize='small')

    return fig, ax


survey(results, category_names)
```